# Intel® XDK: set languages or custom option in AppxManifest

Tags: windows, intel-xdk, windows-dev-center

When I make a windows build, Intel® XDK create the AppxManifest.xml automatically and I need to include an language list resource.
I don't see any option in XDK for define a language list or for include any data in AppxManifest.xml by hand.
How can I do?

Other method: How can I decompress the appx, edit AppxManifest.xml, recompress it and that Win dev center accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, I can decompress the appx generated by XDK with 7zip, include the languages in AppxManifest.xml (in Resources tag) and  repack the folder with makeappx (tool in visual studio comunity 2015 )

In makeappx folder (in  my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86):

makeappx pack /d folder /p output.appx /l